# Minecraft world has no endportal

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I am playing Minecraft: Console Edition on the Xbox, version 1.8.8 in Survival. The seed for my world is 6881183219423020393.

I got some Eyes of Ender and found where to dig. I dug a 10 by 30 block rectangle down into the ground, then found a structure which I thought was the stronghold. I entered the stronghold and explored it, but there were only five rooms or so. Most importantly, **the End Portal was missing**.

So then I dug beyond the ends of the rooms, and any place that looked like it was an unfinished dead end, or some resources in the walls. Nothing.

I dug a 20x40 rectangle down into bedrock. Still nothing.
I went back up, and dug around in the areas above the place where the stronghold is. Nothing.
I dug out the entire strong hold. Nothing.

Then I went to creative mode, and blew up layers in all directions. Still nothing. I went to some other corners of the world, and searched for the stronghold again, but I was led back to the same place. 
I found a crevice at the end of one room. I explored that completely, and found no more strongholds.

Then I went to the MineAtlas site to see if there was information there, but the map they have for my seed doesn't match my map.

I consulted the wiki, and it said that there is only one stronghold per world on the Console Edition.

So... *what should I do?* I'm not too keen on starting over, or having this ever happen again.

**Addendum:** I'm reading that it's a world generator error. Okay, how can I tell if I am in a world that has an error?

Comment: Hold on, is this Xbox 360 or Xbox One?

Comment: Maybe is a bug. If is a bug, we can't do anything. The unique solution is creating a new map.

Comment: ah, this is xbox360.

Comment: Even if it is a bug, how can I know if Im playing in a game with a bug? The nautre of this problem, is that I need to play for a while before I can even discover that the bug is there. I can hope for a new game not having a bug, but I cant verify, until later. Im trying to get teh achievements etc.. which cant be done in creative mode, and I dont want to cheat, I just want to play a glitch free game, or know that Im in a glitched game, and leave it.

Comment: I started a new game, and found the end-portal room (no stronghold) in a room about 30 water blocks down in the middle of the ocean. I'm worried, because that seems like a glitch too.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an error.  It's bad luck.  Ravines can generate anywhere, including right through your portal, and since you mentioned one connected to your stronghold... [Here's the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Stronghold) that states Portal rooms can be overwritten by things, like ravines, caves, mineshafts, etc.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! I'd like to say that if it makes a (kinda) essential feature of the game unplayable, even if just by luck, it is an error/bug. I also edited your answer as your link was broken.

Comment: Oops.  Thanks.  Working from my phone.  You have a point, but I think minecraft's unpredictable seed generation is a feature.  This isn't a problem in pc Minecraft, since the world is procedural.  If one is broken, you look for another.  This is not possible in xbox, so it's certainly somehing for the developers to explore further.